# Como hago para enviar una lista a traves del post

Tags: java, mvc, spring, thymeleaf

estoy haciendo un formulario para crear pokemones, cada uno tiene su nombre y una lista de tipos.
El problema que tengo en si es que quiero enviar la informacion del formulario a la base de datos para guardarlo me da error; lo que me interfiere es que cuando quiero enviar la lista de tipos de pokemon no me deja y me la envia vacia. Como puedo arreglar esto.

---

Tengo esta clase **PokemonModel**

```
public class PokemonModel {

private String nombre;

private List<TipoModel> tipos;

public PokemonModel() {
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public PokemonModel(String nombre, List<TipoModel> tipos) {
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipos = tipos;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public List<TipoModel> getTipos() {
    return tipos;
}

public void setTipos(List<TipoModel> tipos) {
    this.tipos = tipos;
}
```

}

---

El controller **PokemonController**

```
    @GetMapping("/agregar")
public String agregarPokemon(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("pokemon", new PokemonModel());
    model.addAttribute("tipos", tipoService.getAll());
    return "pokemon/agregar";
}

@PostMapping("/agregar")
public String agregarPokemon(@Valid PokemonModel modelo) {
    pokemonService.insertOrUpdate(modelo);
    return "redirect:/app/listar";
```

---

Y mi planilla **agregar.html**

```
    <form th:action="@{/app/agregar}" th:object="${pokemon}" method="post">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Pokemon</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="nombre" th:field="*{nombre}"
                class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Tipos</label>
        <div th:each="tipo: ${tipos}" class="row col-sm-2">
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{tipos}" th:value="${tipo}">
            <label th:text="${tipo.nombre}"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

El error que me muestra es el siguiente
[image: Error]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontre la solucion al problema y es que me faltaba el **@InitBinder** con la clase **editors**

La clase **PokemonController** me quedó así:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app")
@SessionAttributes({"pokemon","evolucion"})
public class PokemonController {
    
    @Autowired
    private PokemonEditors pokemonEditors;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Tipo.class, "tipos", pokemonEditors);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/agregar")
    public String agregarPokemon(Model model) {
        PokemonModel pokemonModel = new PokemonModel();
        model.addAttribute("pokemonModel", pokemonModel);
        return "pokemon/agregar";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/agregar")
    public String agregarPokemones(@ModelAttribute("pokemonModel") PokemonModel pokemonModel) {
        pokemonService.insertOrUpdate(pokemonModel);
        return "redirect:/app/listar";
    }
}
```

creo el editors de la clase **PokemonEditors**

```
@Component
public class PokemonEditors extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    @Autowired
    private ITipoService tipoService;
    
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(text);
            setValue(tipoService.findById(id));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            setValue(null);
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

Y el **agregar.html** quedó asi:

```
<form th:action="@{/app/agregar}" th:object="${pokemonModel}"
    method="post">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label col-sm-1">Nombre</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 ml-3">
            <input type="text" id="nombre" th:field="*{nombre}"
                class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nivel" class="col-form-label col-sm-1">Nivel</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 ml-3">
            <input type="number" id="nivel" th:field="*{nivel}"
                class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row px-3">
        <label for="tipos" class="col-form-label">Tipos</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 px-4 mx-5">
            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{tipos}"
                multiple="multiple">
                <option th:each="tipo: ${listaTipos}" th:field="*{tipos}"
                    th:value="${tipo.id}" th:text="${tipo.nombre}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Subo la respuesta, por si a alguien le sirve de algo. Saludos